# Combine information from 3 tables in one table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables like this

couples

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|couple_id | clubname    | agegroup      | group           |
+----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 36       | club_1      | adults        | C               |
| 37       | club_2      | youth         | A               |
+----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

users:

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+
|couple_id | firstname   | lastname      |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| 36       | andy        | hort          |
| 36       | katrin      | wilson        |
| 37       | hans        | gertes        |
| 37       | julia       | menz          |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

locations for training:

```
+----------+-------------+
|couple_id | location    |
+----------+-------------+
| 36       | Paris       |
| 37       | Berlin      |
| 37       | Paris       |
+----------+-------------+
```

The resulting table should look like this:

```
+---------+------------------------+--------+-----+----------------+
|couple_id| couple                 |agegroup|group|location        |
+---------+------------------------+--------+-----+----------------+
| 36      |andy hort, katrin wilson| adults | C   | Paris          |
| 37      |hans gertes, julia menz | youth  | A   | Paris, Berlin  |
+---------+------------------------+--------+-----+----------------+
```

Is there an elegant query to join these information in one query?

Comment: wondering how you get new york

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Of couse it should be Berlin

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Because first we'll take Manhattan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `group_concat` with `distinct`:

```
select c.couple_id, 
       group_concat(distinct concat(u.firstname, " ", u.lastname)) couple,
       c.agegroup, 
       c.groupd,
       group_concat(distinct l.location) location
from couple c
    join users u on c.couple_id = u.couple_id
    join locations l on c.couple_id = l.couple_id
group by c.couple_id
```

If you have records in the `couple` table that may not exist in the `users` or `locations` table, then you may need to use an `outer join` instead.

---

@spencer7593 makes a great point -- you can move the aggregation to  subqueries to include potential duplicates being removed by `distinct`:

```
select c.couple_id, 
       u.couple,
       c.agegroup, 
       c.groupd,
       l.location
from couple c
    join (
         select couple_id, 
                group_concat(concat(firstname, " ", lastname)) couple
         from users 
         group by couple_id
    ) u on c.couple_id = u.couple_id
    join (
         select couple_id, 
                group_concat(location) location
         from locations
         group by couple_id
    ) l on c.couple_id = l.couple_id
```

Comment: With this approach, I think the `DISTINCT` keyword may be needed in the GROUP_CONCAT.  Two rows from location by two rows from couple is going to produce duplicates. Another approach would be to use an inline view, do the `group_concat` on the couple first. Then join the result from that to `locations`, and do the GROUP_CONCAT on location. (That covers the bizarre edge case where the two individuals in the couple have identical names.)

Comment: @spencer7593 -- 100% agree.  Doing the aggregation in the subquery is probably the better idea.  Updated the answer -- thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try that.

Comment: Likely, OP is going to want `SEPARATOR ', '` in the GROUP_CONCAT (to get the space following the comma. And I'd throw in an `ORDER BY 1` within the GROUP_CONCAT to make the result more deterministic. The outer query could handle the GROUP BY/ GROUP_CONCAT from one of the tables without producing duplicates. But +10 this is how I would do it.